# Edit table modal has different design

Tags: tinymce

When I try to edit a table row on my website, I get this modal:

[image]

But on other websites this modal has a different design:

[image]

I like the second one better. Why does my modal look different? How can I switch to the one the other websites have?

Answer (score 3):

Your screenshots would suggest that you have some CSS on your page that is impacting the TinyMCE dialogs.  If you use the browser's dev tools you should be able to identify what CSS is causing that changed behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The color input fields were [redesigned with TinyMCE 5.2](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/changelog/#version520february132020) so just upgrade to get the new dialog